# Prove or disprove: Proving that a specific mapping is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

For the mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x, y) = (e^{y^2}, \cos(x))$, for every $(x, y)^\top \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exist an open neighborhood $U$ and an open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f|_U: U \rightarrow V$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism.

$\mathbf{my solution}$

To show that for the given mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x, y) = (e^{y^2}, \cos(x))$, there exist an open neighborhood $U$ and an open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f|_U: U \rightarrow V$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism, we need to verify the conditions for a diffeomorphism:

1. $F: U \rightarrow V$ is bijective.
2. $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable ($C^1$).

For the given mapping $f(x, y) = (e^{y^2}, \cos(x))$, we can show that it is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism as follows:

1. Bijection:
   To show that $F: U \rightarrow V$ is bijective, we need to show that it is both injective and surjective.
2. Injectivity:
   Let $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in U$ be such that $F(x_1, y_1) = F(x_2, y_2)$. This implies $(e^{y_1^2}, \cos(x_1)) = (e^{y_2^2}, \cos(x_2))$. By comparing the components, we have $e^{y_1^2} = e^{y_2^2}$ and $\cos(x_1) = \cos(x_2)$. Since the exponential function is injective and the cosine function has a period of $2\pi$, we must have $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$. Therefore, $F$ is injective.
3. Surjectivity:
   For any $(u, v) \in V$, we can find $(x, y) \in U$ such that $F(x, y) = (u, v)$ as follows:

- For the first component, we have $u = e^{y^2}$, which means $y = \sqrt{\ln(u)}$ (choosing the principal square root).
- For the second component, we have $v = \cos(x)$, which gives $x = \arccos(v)$ (choosing the principal value within the range $[0, \pi]$).
  Therefore, we have found $(x, y)$ such that $F(x, y) = (u, v)$, showing that $F$ is surjective.

Since $F$ is both injective and surjective, it is bijective.

2. Continuously Differentiable ($C^1$):
   To show that $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable ($C^1$), we need to show that their partial derivatives exist and are continuous.

Let's calculate the partial derivatives of $F$ and $F^{-1}$:

Partial derivatives of $F$:
$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} = 0$,
$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y} = 2ye^{y^2}$,
$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} = -\sin(x)$,
$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} = 0$.

Partial derivatives of $F^{-1}$:
$\frac{\partial F_1^{-1}}{\partial u} = 0$,
$\frac{\partial F_1^{-1}}{\partial v} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}v}$,
$\frac{\partial F_2^{-1}}{\partial u} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$,
$\frac{\partial F_2^{-1}}{\partial v} = 0$.

All these partial derivatives are defined and continuous for $(x, y) \in U$ and $(u, v) \in V$, respectively. Therefore, $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable ($C^1$).

Since $F$ is bijective and both $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable ($C^1$), we can conclude that $f|_U: U \rightarrow V$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism.

Hence, for the given mapping $f(x, y) = (e^{y^2}, \cos(x))$, there exist an open neighborhood $U$ and an open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f|_U: U \rightarrow V$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism.

I'm pretty much unsure that my solution is correct and I woule really appreciate your help.

Comment: The solution is not corret, $e^{y^2}$ is not injective, $e^{(-1)^2} = e^{(1)^2}$. Moreover suppose the property is true for a certain $(x,y)$ with $y = 0$, since $f_U$ is a diffeomorphism it admits an inverse $g_V$ and you have $g_V(f_U(x,y)) = (x,y)$, taking the jacobian both sides you find $J_g(f_U(x,y)) \cdot J_f(x,y) = \mathbf{1}$, so $J_f(x,y)$ is invertible, but since $y= 0$ you can see that $J_f(x,y)$ is not invertible. Therefore the property can't be true for any $(x,y)$ with $y = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is in fact not true. I'll show that the injectivity requirement fails at $(0,0)$ (there are *many* other points where it fails as well, see if you can find them). For this, it suffices to show that that $f|_{B_r(0)}$ is not injective for any $r>0$, as all open neighborhoods of $(0,0)$ contain such balls.

Fix $r>0$, and notice that

$$f\left(\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{2}\right)=\left(e^{\frac{r^2}{4}},\cos\frac{r}{2}\right)=\left(e^{\frac{r^2}{4}},\cos\left(-\frac{r}{2}\right)\right)=f\left(-\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{2}\right)$$

since $\cos$ is even. However clearly $\left(\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{2}\right)\neq\left(-\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{2}\right)$, and so $f|_{B_r(0)}$ is not injective.

---

Let's now analyze why your supposed injectivity argument fails. You claim that because $\cos$ is $2\pi$-periodic, you can conclude that if $\cos x_1=\cos x_2$, then $x_1=x_2$. This is just complete nonsense, and in fact $2\pi$-periodicity directly implies that this is not the case, as $\cos x=\cos(x+2\pi)$. What you *can* say though, is that if you look at a sufficiently small set, then a similar conclusion holds. In particular, $\cos$ *is* locally injective around the points where $\sin$ is non-zero.

A very similar issue arises with your treatment of $y\mapsto e^{y^2}$, as this in fact also not invertible, as $e^{(-y)^2}=e^{y^2}$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$. You cannot simply just compare the arguments, as this already implies that you have injectivity, which you do not.

Another issue in your solution is that the set $U$ is never actually specified. You actually need to find such a set, since the problem asks you whether it even exists to begin with. Reading your solution, for all I know, you could be working with anything from

$$U=\mathbb{R}^2$$

to

$$U=\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\left(x+j-\frac{1}{2^{\lvert j\rvert}},x+j+\frac{1}{2^{\lvert j\rvert}}\right)\times(y-1,y+1)\right).$$

*You need to be explicit*, and also you really need to make sure you understand what the problem gives you, and what the problem asks you to produce. For this particular problem what you are given is

- a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$,
- an arbitrary point $(x,y)$ (more specifically you are given all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$)

and what you are asked to come up with, or show doesn't exist, is

- open sets $U,V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ with $(x,y)\in U$ satisfying that $f|_U:U\to V$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism.

Notice, however, that you start your solution by assuming the existence of $U$, which you cannot do.

---

I'll end by remarking that I haven't really looked closely at the rest of your attempt, however I do feel like the things I have commented on are enough here, and with how you seem to have confused a lot of things, and have written it in a way which is very unclear to a reader, I'll leave it at this. Hopefully it answers your question enough though.